# Hide JSP error icons in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse

Working with Eclipse (or rather, an IDE built on top of Eclipse, but all Eclipse factoids apply to it) for Java development on the web, with a handful of EARs housing a host of web apps. The thing is, problems in the JSPs and web code have nothing to do with the classes and servlets I spend all day digging through; I'm wondering if I can configure the red flag icons by each project to show up only when there are errors in Java code and not WebContent. Anyone have any idea how to configure the icons to only show on Java problems and not JSP problems?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Can can either configure this at workspace level or overwrite at web project level.

**Workspace**

Window -> Preferences -> Validation -> disable JSP Content Validator & JSP Syntax Validator

Window -> Preferences -> Web -> JSP Files -> disable Validate JSP Fragments

**Web project**

Properties -> Validation -> disable JSP Content Validator & JSP Syntax Validator

Properties -> Validation -> JSP Syntax -> disable Validate JSP Fragments

Answer (score 3):

Go to Window -> Preferences search for jsp,

[image: JSP preferences page]

You can configure the level of validations to be performed even on project levels.
Hope it helps.